# Download packages without installing

Tags: apt, package-management

I want to download packages from the Ubuntu archive without fully installing them. The default `sudo apt install` downloads and installs them. I only want to download them. Is this possible?

Comment: You can also download them from: https://packages.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is possible to download packages without installing them. This is often used in cases where internet access on another computer is not available, and one needs to be able to sideload the packages onto the machine. Here is what you do:

1. Remove any packages currently saved in the cache by running `sudo apt clean`.
2. Include `--download-only` in the command, e.g: `sudo apt install --download-only <NameOfPackage>`. This also works for multiple packages, e.g: `sudo apt install --download-only <package1> <package2> <package3>`

All packages downloaded via this method will be saved in the `/var/cache/apt/archives` directory. You'll be able to copy them to your desired location or leave them there for future `sudo apt install` operations.

Comment: `apt download` is quite simple.

Comment: Very nice. Can you download multiple packages that way: sudo apt-get install -d [package1] [package2] [package3]

Comment: @Broadsworde You certainly can!