# install canon pixma ip4950 to ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, canon

Downloaded iP4900 series IJ Printer Driver Ver. 3.60 for Linux (debian Packagearchive) from canon-europe.com. It has 2 unmet dependencies - libpng12-0 and libtiff4. The first is done by installing libpng16-16. libtiff4, however, cannot be found.
How can I install this printer driver?

Comment: What about `libtiff5` and `libtiff5-dev`?

Comment: `libtiff4` http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tiff/ → **2015-04-01** → http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tiff/libtiff4_3.9.2-2ubuntu0.16_amd64.deb  . And `libpng12-0`, frrom Ubuntu 16.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206167/download-packages-without-installing/1206168#1206168 → `sudo apt install --reinstall --download-only libpng12-0` ..... Both packages saved to https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DUKKvui64R5gqVdhxYn-31y8HXmP8lxe?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> iP4900 series IJ Printer Driver ...
> has 2 unmet dependencies - libpng12-0
> and libtiff4

You can get both packages from the old archive, example tiff http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tiff/ → 2015-04-01 → → http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tiff/libtiff4_3.9.2-2ubuntu0.16_amd64.deb

Example `libpng12-0`, from an Ubuntu 16.04 install, ref.  [Download packages without installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206167/download-packages-without-installing/1206168#1206168)

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall --download-only libpng12-0
```

Packages `libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb,  libtiff4_3.9.2-2ubuntu0.16_amd64.deb` were saved to https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DUKKvui64R5gqVdhxYn-31y8HXmP8lxe?usp=sharing